# How to groupby or exclude based on value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a df where the groupby looks like this

```
   +----------------+----------------+-------------+
   | Team           | Method         |  Count      |
   +----------------+----------------+-------------+
   | Team 1         | Manual         |          14 |
   | Team 2         | Automated      |           5 |
   | Team 2         | Hybrid         |           1 |
   | Team 2         | Manual         |          25 |
   | Team 4         | Automated      |           1 |
   | Team 4         | Hybrid         |          13 |
   +----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I would like to create a count or groupby showing Teams that only have Manual Methods. Any idea how I could go about doing that?

In the case of this data set, the answer would be Team 1, since they are the only team with only Manual Methods.

Comment: I think you can use subset - `df[df['Method'].isin(['Manual'])].groupby...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for all values `Manual` by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) and use subset by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
print df
      Team     Method
0   Team 1     Manual
1   Team 1     Manual
2   Team 1     Manual
3   Team 1     Manual
4   Team 1     Manual
5   Team 2  Automated
6   Team 2  Automated
7   Team 2  Automated
8   Team 2  Automated
9   Team 2  Automated
10  Team 2     Hybrid
11  Team 2     Manual
12  Team 2     Manual
13  Team 3     Manual
14  Team 2     Manual
15  Team 2     Manual
16  Team 4  Automated
17  Team 4     Hybrid
```

```
g = df.groupby("Team")['Method'].apply( lambda x: (x == 'Manual').all())
print g
Team
Team 1     True
Team 2    False
Team 3     True
Team 4    False
Name: Method, dtype: bool

print g[g.values].index
Index([u'Team 1', u'Team 3'], dtype='object', name=u'Team')

print df.loc[df['Team'].isin(g[g.values].index)]
      Team  Method
0   Team 1  Manual
1   Team 1  Manual
2   Team 1  Manual
3   Team 1  Manual
4   Team 1  Manual
13  Team 3  Manual
```

For better understanding `apply`, you can use custom function `f` with `print`, which compare each item of groups with string `Manual`:

```
def f(x):
    print(x == 'Manual')

print df.groupby("Team")['Method'].apply(f)
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: Team 1, dtype: bool
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
Name: Team 2, dtype: bool
15    False
16    False
Name: Team 4, dtype: bool
```

But we need check if all values are string `Manual` - it means we need check if all values are `True` with `all`:

```
def f(x):
    print(x == 'Manual').all()

print df.groupby("Team")['Method'].apply(f)
True
False
False
```

EDIT: I added sample with `groupby` with 2 columns:

```
print df
      Col1     Method  Col2
0   Team 1     Manual  Team
1   Team 1     Manual  Team
2   Team 1     Manual  Team
3   Team 1     Manual  Team
4   Team 1     Manual  Team
5   Team 2  Automated  Team
6   Team 2  Automated  Team
7   Team 2  Automated  Team
8   Team 2  Automated  Team
9   Team 2  Automated  Team
10  Team 2     Hybrid  Team
11  Team 2     Manual  Team
12  Team 2     Manual  Team
13  Team 3     Manual  Team
14  Team 2     Manual  Team
15  Team 2     Manual  Team
16  Team 4  Automated  Team
17  Team 4     Hybrid  Team
```

```
g = df.groupby(["Col1", "Col2"])['Method'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'Manual').all())
print g
Col1    Col2
Team 1  Team     True
Team 2  Team    False
Team 3  Team     True
Team 4  Team    False
Name: Method, dtype: bool

g =  g.reset_index()
print g
     Col1  Col2 Method
0  Team 1  Team   True
1  Team 2  Team  False
2  Team 3  Team   True
3  Team 4  Team  False

g1 = g.loc[g['Method'], 'Col1']
print g1
0    Team 1
2    Team 3
Name: Col1, dtype: object

print df.loc[df['Col1'].isin(g1.values)]
      Col1  Method  Col2
0   Team 1  Manual  Team
1   Team 1  Manual  Team
2   Team 1  Manual  Team
3   Team 1  Manual  Team
4   Team 1  Manual  Team
13  Team 3  Manual  Team
```

Comment: What I am trying to get is the name of the teams with only Manual processes. So the end result in this df would be Team 1, since Team 1 only has manual, Team 2 has all types, and Team 4 has no manual. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, any chance you can walk me through what is happening there?

Comment: Also as a noob, how did you think that through? I tried everything I know and didn't even get close to that.

Comment: Sorry, I found error, because I try add new row with `Team 3` and output was wrong. So solution is edited. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting a few errors when I try the updated code
I

Comment: I am getting an error when I try the updated code

     g = df.groupby("Team")['Method'].apply( lambda x: (x == 'Manual').all())

When I call ("Team"), I get an error "No axis named "Team" for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. 

No problem when I call (['Team'])
Does that change anything?

Comment: I am also getting type(g) as a series, not as an object.

Comment: What is `print df.columns`?

Comment: `g` is `Series`, it is OK.

Comment: I am trying to apply this to a slightly more complicated DF with another column to add. Is there a way to use this formula with two columns like this

g = df.groupby("Col 1", "Col 2")['Method'].apply( lambda x: (x == 'Manual').all())

Comment: Yes, it is possible - you can use `g = df.groupby(["Col1", "col2"])['Method'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'Manual').all())`

Comment: I try add dample with groupby with 2 columns - maybe help.